# Compute all possible values of log(-j)

Tags: complex-numbers

How do I find all possible values of $\log(-j)$? 
I need to use the equation

[image]

Comment: y=-1, x=0. Convert to polar coordinates.

Comment: ok but that's the part I'm confused and I don't know to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case $x=0$ and $y=-1$. Converting to polar coordinates $r=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}=1$ and $\theta = \arcsin{\frac{y}{r}} = - \frac{\pi}{2}$.
So $\log{(-j)} = j (- \frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi k)$